# Facebook comments plugin broken in IE8

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-8, facebook-comments

I'm running the Facebook Comments plugin (API v2.3) on my website. Recently in IE8 the comments do not load and the following error is thrown:

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

It was working fine a few weeks ago and I checked on Facebook's own demo page and some other websites that implement it and it's not working there either. I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation, have they stopped supporting IE8?

Comment: You could consider filing a bug report at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs, however since a very small portion of users are still using IE 8, and even Microsoft will be dropping support in a matter of months, the likelihood of the this being fixed is probably slim.

Comment: I filed a bug report but their answer was that they have no way of testing in IE8. All I need is confirmation that the plugin doesn't support IE8 anymore.